# Conflict jQuery with Bootstrap in symfony2

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I have problem with jquery and bootstrap in my project which I am writing in Symfony 2.

```
    <script src="{{ asset('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
```

I have a problem with bootstrap lightbox. I tried two plugin:
nor Boostrap lightbox nor jquery.simple.lightbox don't work. In both cases I have identically problem:

when I click - I see only effect shadow. I can't see image. What does it happen? Why these scripts don't work?

```
    <a data-toggle="lightbox" href="#demoLightbox">
                <img src="{{ asset("avatars/") ~ us.avatar }}" class='small' />

    </a>

<div id="demoLightbox" class="lightbox hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class='lightbox-dialog'>
        <div class="lightbox-content">
            <img src="{{ asset("avatars/") ~ us.avatar }}" />
            <div class="lightbox-caption">
                <p> This is an avatar </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

above src to image are valid and in the firebug i see images.

I would like to add that my forms with bootstrap work great and looks like that bootstrap is valid in my project.

Comment: Based on the error, you are referencing an element by an id that does not exist. Can you post in which file at which line it throws an error?

Comment: @FrEaKmAn  

... d(a,b)}};b.cache={},b.load=function(a){return document.getElementById(a).innerH...

 
tmpl.min.js (row 1, column 291)

Comment: based on the error, where are you using that library? can you post more code

Comment: @FrEaKmAn ok, i got it. The list is now display but I have now problem with e function. TypeError: e is undefined in jquery.min.js. Do u have any ideas?

Comment: Need more info. Where it happens?

Comment: @FrEaKmAn I created template where I display user's profile. In this template I would like to have avatar that user. After click avatar (image with class="small" I should see these image in full size. But after click I see only grey background, like shadow.

Comment: It's really hard to debug. Can you please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can see it?